# Crystal Report C# final exam summary

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports

I am creating examination report in C#
i added a cross-tab crystal report to report first term exam marks for every class
so now i want to alter the second term reporting to the previos term and make a total from the both terms

[image]

this is the output
[image]

Comment: Add group for term1 and term2 and then sum by specified group.

Answer (score 0):

Add {Term} as a column to the CrossTab.